# How to tell ajax to get the selected data and retrive a data from the database acquired to the selected data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I have 2 select boxes. the first one is to select the brand, the second one to select the product. what I want is that the second select box gets the data from the database which have the same brand_name as the first select box. I don't have any clue about AJAX. I've got this script from a friend but it's not working...
that what is my database look like:

The "brands" database:

```
brand_id | brand_name
    1    | ADIDAS
    2    | NIKE
```

and here is my "product" database:

```
product_id | brand_name | product_name | product_image | amount | sell | buy
     1     |   ADIDAS   |    T-Shirt   |     none      |   50   |  30  | 28
     2     |   NIKE     |    Shoes     |     none      |   20   |  130 | 120
```

and here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>TEST | INDEX</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" lang="en">
  <script src="ajax.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <select required="required" name="brand_name">
    <option disabled selected>----SELECT----</option>
    <?php 
      require_once 'connections/dbc.php';
      $query = "SELECT `brand_name` FROM `brands`";
      $response = @mysqli_query($conn, $query);
      if (!$response) {
        $_SESSION['errortitle'] ='Error loading the brands';
        $_SESSION['errormessage'] = 'Something wrong happend while loading the brands.<br/>Please contact The developer';
        header("location: error.php");
        exit();
      } else {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response)){
          echo '<option value='.$row['brand_name'].'>'.$row['brand_name'].'</option>';
        }
      }
    ?>
  </select>
<select required="required" name="product_name" disabled>
  <option disabled selected >SELECT</option>
    <?php

    ?>
</select>
<script>
    $('[name = "brand_name"]').change(function(event){
        var brand_name = $(this).val();
       $.get( 
          "action/ajax.php",
          { brand_name: brand_name },
          function(data) {
            var opts = $.parseJSON(data);
                $.each(opts, function(i, d) {
                    $('[name="product_name"]').append($('<option>', {
                        value: d.product_name,
                        text : d.product_name
                    }));
                });
                //Enable the product_name select box
                $('[name="product_name"]').prop('disabled', false);
                //Refresh the product_name select box
                $('[name="product_name"]').selectpicker('refresh');
          }
       );
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

and here is the ajax.php code:

```
<?php
    require_once '../connections/dbc.php';

    $getBrandName = $_REQUEST['brand_name']; // This is the id of the selected brand name
    $query = "SELECT 'product_name' FROM `product` WHERE brand_name = '$getBrandName' ";
    $response = @mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    if (!$response) {
        echo "Error loading the prouducts";
        echo 'Something wrong happend while loading the proudcts.<br/>Please contact The developer';
        exit();
    } else {
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response)){
            $productsArray[]['name'] = $row['product_name'];
        }
        echo json_encode($brandName);
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: When you say it's not working, what isn't working?  A little more info here would be good.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want your second dropdown to be populated based on the selection of your first dropdown?

Comment: Do you get any response in your browser’s dev tools?  Click F12 in Chrome, click the Network tab and filter only XHR types. Check and see what status code is returned here. If 200 then you are probably getting the data and the problem is JavaScript. If you return a 400 or 500 code then the problem is likely server side.

Comment: @webdevsoup The thing which isn't working is that i dont get any data in the second select box after chossing the data from the first box####### note that the second box become available after selecting data from the first box which means that the JavaScript is response for the script where told to enable it after selecting ........

Comment: @ObsidianAge yes like if i set the brand at adidas the second box must show my only the product which have the same brand_name

Comment: @sthurston yes it's giving me a 200

Comment: you're echoing `$brandName` which contains nothing. change it to `echo json_encode($productsArray);`

Comment: @bowl0stu well this made some different but hes giving my an empty option......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
require_once 'connections/dbc.php';

// Get our brands
$query = "SELECT `brand_name` FROM `brands`";
$response = @mysqli_query($conn, $query);
if (!$response) {
    $_SESSION['errortitle'] = 'Error loading the brands';
    $_SESSION['errormessage'] = 'Something wrong happend while loading the brands.<br/>Please contact The developer';
    header("location: error.php");
    exit();
} else {
    $brands = mysqli_fetch_array($response);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TEST | INDEX</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" lang="en">
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('[name = "brand_name"]').change(function (event) {
                var brand_name = $(this).val();
                $.get(
                    "action/ajax.php",
                    {brand_name: brand_name},
                    function (data) {
                        var opts = JSON.parse(data);
                        $.each(opts, function (i, d) {
                            $('[name="product_name"]').append('<option>', {
                                value: d.product_name,
                                text: d.product_name
                            });
                        });
                        //Enable the product_name select box
                        $('[name="product_name"]').prop('disabled', false);
                        //Refresh the product_name select box
                        $('[name="product_name"]').selectpicker('refresh');
                    }
                );
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<select required="required" name="brand_name">
    <option disabled selected>----SELECT----</option>
    <?php
    foreach ($brands as $row) {
        echo '<option value=' . $row['brand_name'] . '>' . $row['brand_name'] . '</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select>
<select required="required" name="product_name" disabled>
    <option disabled selected>SELECT</option>

</select>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it's not working... he's showing me tow option to select and they are a "Z" in the first select box. it's not even giving me the brands...

Comment: and he's telling my that the $ is not defined

Comment: the $ which bellow to the $(document).ready(function () { in the line 8

Comment: @AssadRajab - I updated my answer to use `JSON.parse` instead of `$.parseJSON`